# How to find the Laurent series expansion of an exp function.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, laurent-series

> **Question:**

How to find the Laurent series expansion in powers of z of

a) $f(z)= \dfrac{e^{z^2}}{z^3}$ $\text{where} \left| z \right| > 0$

> **Attempt:**
>
> I know that the main idea is to rearrange the equation in such a way that you can use standard Tylor series such as:
>
> $e^x$ which is given as $\displaystyle \sum \frac{x^n}{n!}$

But how do you do this, and what is the method to tackle L series questions?

> **Edit:**
>
> After looking at some of the comments, would this method be correct:
>
> $f(z)= \dfrac{e^{z^2}}{z^3}$ 
>   $f(z)= \dfrac{1}{z^3} e^{z^2}$ 
>   $f(z)= \dfrac{1}{z^3} \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(z^2)^n}{n!}$ 
>   L.series?
>   $f(z)= \dfrac{1}{z^3} \biggl(1+z^2+\dfrac{z^4}{2!}+\dfrac{z^6}{3!}+...\biggr)$

Comment: Can you write down the Tylor series for $\exp(z^2)$?

Comment: i'm assuming you take the ($z^2$) and put it where $x^n$ is in the above Tylor series?

Comment: Your last edit looks correct.

Comment: No, the last line is missing the $z^2$ term inside the parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes your answer is correct. Since the taylor series of $e^{x}$ converges absolutely it is the same as the laurent series. Now if you want to you can simplify.

$\frac{1}{z^{3}}\sum\frac{z^{2n}}{n!}$

$\sum\frac{z^{2n-3}}{n!}$

Which expands as...

$$\frac{1}{z^3}+\frac{1}{z}+\frac{z}{2!}+\frac{z^3}{3!}...$$