# The expansion of $e^x$ without Taylor series

Tags: power-series, exponential-function

As I mentioned in the title, I want to find the expansion of $e^x$ using only the definition of $e=\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+1/n)^n$, and by developing it we find the sum of the infinite series. How do I prove it?

Comment: Maybe a [Laurent Series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1793007/how-to-find-the-laurent-series-expansion-of-an-exp-function) would help, but I am not used to it.

Comment: Would heuristics (a' la Euler) be a good start for you? Please advise...

Comment: @TymaGaidash A Laurent series is essentially the same thing

Comment: Showing that the coefficient of $x^k$ in $(1+\tfrac x n)^n$ for some fixed $k$ convergers to $1/k!$ for $n \to \infty$ seems like a good start.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/54499) answer your question?

Comment: @paulgarrett i'm sorry i don't know what that is but i would love to know thanks

Comment: @WimC i went with that reasoning but i found a problem when k is equal to n or even close to it because it's a summation that formula has to be true for all coefficients x^k but that's not the case

Comment: @robjohn yes thank you this really helped

Answer (score 2):

We know that $e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+x/n)^n$. Expanding the binomial gives us:

$$\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}\frac{x^k}{n^k}$$

Therefore,

\begin{align*}
e^x&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}\frac{x^k}{n^k}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[1+x+\frac{n(n-1)}{n^2}\cdot\frac{x^2}{2!}+\dots+\frac{n(n-1)\ldots(n-k+1)}{n^{n-k+1}}\frac{x^k}{k!}+\dots\right]\\
&=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\dots+\frac{x^k}{k!}+\dots\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}
\end{align*}

There are some details that would need to be filled in to make this  a proper proof, but this is the general idea.

Comment: this is the method that i went with , but there is an issue , the formula is correct to a certain k because we get 1 when n tends to infinity , but what about when k is equal to n the limit isn't 1 , using the same formula i get n!/(n^n) which tends to 0

Comment: @procrastinatingscholar, this argument is what I was thinking of as a "good heuristic", meaning that it quite correctly and strongly suggests the correct conclusion, but needs a little augmentation to be a proof.